# Matching coefficients of polynomial congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I was reading about the AKS Primality test when the following proof threw me off a bit. The following proof is given directly from the original paper Primes in P by Agrawal, Kayal and Saxena.

**Lemma 2.1**. Let $a\in \mathbb{Z}$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $n\geq2$, and $\gcd(a, n) = 1$. Then $n$ is prime if and only if

$(X + a)^n \equiv X^n + a\ (mod\ n)$

Proof: For $0 < i < n$, the coefficient of $x^i$ in $(X + a)^n − (X^n + a)$ is
$\binom{n}{i}a^{n-i}$.

Suppose n is prime. Then $\binom{n}{i}\equiv0\ (mod\ n)$ and hence all coefficients are zero.

Suppose n is composite. Consider a prime $q$ that is a factor of $n$ and let $q^{k}$ be the highest power of $q$ to divide $n$. Then $q^k$ does not divide $\binom{n}{q}$ and is coprime to $a^{n-q}$ and hence the coefficient of $X^q$ is not zero $(mod\ n)$. Thus $(X + a)^n − (X^n + a)$ is not identically zero over $\mathbb{Z}_n$. $\square$

My problem is with the last portion of the proof where they say that $(X + a)^n − (X^n + a)$ is not identically zero over $\mathbb{Z}_n$. How can we be sure that there is no *weird* relationships (unlikely as it may) between the surviving coefficients that allows the polynomial to be zero even though there are terms surviving (for example, $x^p - x$ over a prime modulus). All other proofs I've found of this lemma appeal to some type of coefficient comparison, i.e. the coefficient is zero on the right hand side but non-zero on the left. Contradiction.

It is my understanding that direct comparison of polynomial coefficients cannot be done with congruences, so can someone please explain this to me? Perhaps a more general question would be: When is it permissible to equate coefficients of two polynomial congruences?

Comment: They might mean that it's non-zero as an element of $\mathbf Z_n[X]$ -- by which I mean the ring of formal linear combinations of the $X^i$ with coefficients in $\mathbf Z_n$ with the usual multiplication -- and not as a function $\mathbf Z_n \to \mathbf Z_n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AKS argument quoted in the question shows that if $n$ is composite, and $\gcd(a,n)=1$, then the polynomial $P(X)=(X+a)^n -(X^n+a)$ is not the zero polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}_n$.  This means that at least one coefficient of $P(X)$ is not congruent to $0$ modulo $n$.

But in the statement of the result, the phrase "is not identically zero over $\mathbb{Z}_n$" is used.  This prompted you to ask whether there are composite $n$ such that $P(X)$, viewed as a **polynomial function** from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to $\mathbb{Z}_n$, is the identically zero *function*.

The answer, surprisingly, is **yes, there are** infinitely many such $n$.  Let $n$ be a [Carmichael number.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number)

A *Carmichael number* is usually defined as a composite number $n$ such that $x^{n-1} \equiv 1\pmod{n}$ for every $x$ relatively prime to $n$.  However, one can prove that if $n$ is a Carmichael number, then $x^n \equiv x\pmod{n}$ for *every* $x$. The proof uses the *Korselt Criterion* described in the Wikipedia article.

The smallest Carmichael number is $561=3\cdot 11\cdot 17$. The key property that makes everything work is that $3-1$, $11-1$, and $17-1$ all divide $560$. The rest follows from Fermat's Theorem.

If $n$ is a Carmichael number, then $(x+a)^n \equiv x+a \pmod{n}$ for every $x\in \mathbb{N}$.  Also, $x^n+a \equiv x+a \pmod{n}$.  It follows that $P(X)$, viewed as a polynomial function, is identically zero.

**Note**: There are infinitely many Carmichael numbers.  In fact, they are moderately "common," though the proof that there are infinitely many is less than $20$ years old.  This result, by Alford, Granville, and Pomerance, settled a longstanding conjecture.

Comment: Thank you, that was very precise. But for further clarification, does that mean the proof provided for the theorem above is then invalid?

Comment: The proof is a valid proof that if $n$ is composite, not all the coefficients of the polynomial on the left are congruent to the corresponding coefficient of the polynomial on the right.  So the **coefficients** of the difference polynomial are not all congruent to $0$.  My example shows that it is possible for the polynomial **function** to be identically $0$.  That's the question you asked.  Here is a simple example of a similar phenomenon. Let $p$ be prime.  The polynomial $X^p -X$ is not, as a polynomial, the zero polynomial, two of its coefficients are $1$, which is not congruent to $0$.

Comment: (continued) However, for all $a\in \mathbb{Z}_p$, $a^p-a$ is congruent to $0$ modulo $p$.  In any *infinite* field, if the coefficients of the polynomial $P(X)$ are not all $0$ in the field, there is an $a$ in the field such that $P(a)\ne 0$.  Finite fields don't have his property. So in general one has to distinguish between polynomial and polynomial function.

Comment: I'm starting to get what you are saying. I apologize for the confusion since I've never been exposed to these concepts before. I think I am misunderstanding the meaning of the theorem. The theorem is stating that the two polynomial functions must be "equal" (I think formal congruence is the term from PlanetMath) while I interpreted it as the values of the two polynomials must be congruent. Thanks again for your help by the way.

Comment: As I point out in the answer, "not identically zero over $\mathbb{Z}_n$" is deeply ambiguous.  Probably the interpretation "as a function," which you made, is the more natural one.  But that's not what they *prove*, what they prove is that the polynomials are not formally congruent.  What my post shows is that it is possible, first case $n=561$, for the *values* to be always congruent.